# Relay(or Alternative of relay) without pull-back feature

Tags: relay

Generally relay triggers when current passes through its coil. When current stops flowing, moving terminal of relay is pulled back into the default situation. I need relay, once triggered, to remain in that situation only regardless of the current. In short, I want the relay without spring. I am pretty sure that this kind of relay doesn't exist, but there must be a component which satisfies this requirements. I mostly work on Digital and FPGA side, so I don't have enough knowledge about Analog.If anyone can suggest me a component which fits here, it will be very helpful for me

Comment: Do you mean a _latching relay_?

Answer (score 5):

What the question describes is called a **[latching relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Latching_relay)**:

[image: Schematic]

There are several types of latching relay manufactured: NO/NC/NO+NC, SPDT/DPDT, timed reset, switch reset, and so on.

Depending on required rating and load type, latching relays are available in tiny sugar-cube type PCB mounted packages, all the way up to industrial versions.

Also, they come in both solid state, and electromagnetic types.